# How to read <br> tags from sql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to add 
 to my sql field so that when I load it will show something like this.

a
b
c

currently it shows

a
b
c

My script:

into sql

```
string1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(ODBCdataset.Tables("table1").Rows(0).Item(10))
```

and to read it I'm using

```
response.write(string1)
```

If I do it with ADO.net it shows 
a
b
c

but when I use vb.net, it shows the 
 as well. All help appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT

I found that all I needed was to add `Response.Write(Server.HtmlDecode(string1))` and it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that all I needed was to add `Response.Write(Server.HtmlDecode(string1))` and it worked.

Comment: So why did you encode it in the first place? You could achieve the same result by doing this `string1.Text = ODBCdataset.Tables("table1").Rows(0).Item(10)`

Comment: If I didn't encode it, it would give me an error saying <br> is harmful.. funny thing is there were no such problems in ADO, just aspx...

Comment: ADO and ASPX are two different things so your comment doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method this:

```
string1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(ODBCdataset.Tables("table1").
                   Rows(0).Item(10)).Replace("<br>","")
```

Note: you might have a slightly different br tag than that

**EDIT:**

Seems that as you are using HtmlDecode it is turning `<br>` into `&lt;br&gt;` so just do this instead:

```
string1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(ODBCdataset.Tables("table1").
                   Rows(0).Item(10)).Replace("&lt;br&gt;","")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not working. I checked my sql server, it's still &lt;br&gt;

Comment: It's still showing the <br>... But I've found an answer for it. Thanks for the help :)